# How to printf fixed number or digits in floating in bash

Tags: bash, printf

I want to output floating numbers with exact number of digits without padding in the front, since I want to prepend `$` sign
For example I read numbers:

```
1.2345
12.345
123.456
```

and I want output:

```
$1.23450
$12.3450
$123.456
```

I tried many different variations in printf but can't fix number of total digits.  I also didn't find answer to this particular problem
`printf "$%.7f\n" 1.2345 12.345 123.456` 
neither with `"$%.7f\n` `"$%07f\n` `"$%6.4f\n` `"$%.7g\n` 
Do I need to get different formatting for for different magnitude of numbers ie 1, 10, 100?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to printf fixed number or digits in floating in bash

Print first 7 characters from the printed number.

```
printf '$%.7s\n' "$(printf '%.6f' 1234.2345)"
```

> Do I need to get different formatting for for different magnitude of numbers ie 1, 10, 100?

Yes, you should implement your own formatting function for custom formatting requirements. There is no such printf formatting specifier for what you want.

Comment: Also `printf` for floating-point numbers in Bash should be avoided, because the input format is dependent on the `LC_NUMERIC` locale. It will break and error if using dot decimal on locales with a comma decimal, and the other way using comma on dot decimal locales.

Comment: I suggest to replace second `printf` with `LC_NUMERIC=C printf`.

Comment: Thanks @LéaGris but what to substitute for `%f`

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk,  This works as I wanted to. Given with one parameter, but I can loop it for other parameters

Comment: `Given with one paramete` you could do `printf "$%.7s\n" $(printf "%.6f" 1234.2345 1 2 3 )`

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried this but it only displays first argument

Comment: `LC_NUMERIC locale.` yea, that's why I am picky with my locale, I have LC_CTYPE, LC_TIME, LC_PAPER set to pl_PL.UTf-8, and the rest to en_US.

Comment: `nly displays first argument ` och right a space is missing. `printf "$%.7s\n" $(printf "%.6f " 1234.2345 1 2 3 )`

Comment: @KamilCuk it still doesn't work for me with multiple arguments.
Also can I substitute `6` with variable $len so I can modify on the fly?

Comment: work fine here https://replit.com/@kamilcukrowski/PossibleMealyState#main.sh and prints 4 separate lines `can I substitute 6 with variable` `"%.${len}f "`...

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes it works, you removed quotes also from second `printf`  ... Thanks for `${len}` .  All solved !

Comment: $ printf "$%.7s\n" "$(printf "%.6f" 1234,2345)" otherwise error

Comment: $ printf "\$%.7f \n"  "1,2345"

Comment: @Alex `otherwise error` What error?

Comment: $ printf '$%.7s\n' "$(printf '%.6f' 1234.2345)"
bash: printf: 1234.2345: invalid number
$0,00000

Comment: Your locale uses `,` as decimal separator, not `.`. Adjust what you type or adjust your locale `LC_NUMERIC`. See `locale` `man 7 locale` and https://lh.2xlibre.net/locales/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to using floating-point formatting in Bash:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

float_numbers=(1.2345 12.345 123.456)

# Get the longest number's length
for float in "${float_numbers[@]}"; do
  max_length=$((${#float} > max_length ? ${#float} : max_length))
done

for float in "${float_numbers[@]}"; do
  # Generate needed padding
  printf -v padding '%-*s' $((max_length - ${#float})) ''

  # Print $float followed by its 0 padding
  printf '$%s%s\n' "$float" "${padding// /0}"
done
```